# What is a good way to change a group of users UIDs without usermod executing a time consuming chown on the user home directory?

Tags: users

**My situation**

I inherited a collection of four Linux boxes where no care was taken to keep UIDs unique across systems.   There are ~40 users and over 7TB of data owned collectively by those users.

In order to have some sanity when NFS mounting /data volumes between these four boxes, I need to get the UIDs matching.  I also want to minimize
the amount of time users are asked to stay logged out while I perform this change.

Because of the number of users and amount of data, I have written a  program to chown (in one pass of the ~7TB) all the files from current state UIDs to fixed state UIDs for all 40 users.   At the end of this, I'll need to change /etc/passwd so that the usernames match the new fixed state UIDs.

This would be simpler if I only had one user to fix and/or if there were less data to crawl through and chown.

I had thought that after running my program to change file permissions I would simply run

```
usermod -u fixedUID jsmith -o
```

For each of the 40 users.  However,  the manual for usermod suggests it is going to do it's own chown of the files in /home/jsmith (thus defeting my attempt at a simple pass fix).  I can't figure out how to disable this and I'm worried the final usermod step is going to turn my 1-pass fix into a 41-pass fix.

**My question**

How would you change the users UIDs after chowning everything on the file system? Is there a better way than "vipw" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing the user's home directory temporarily (e.g. to `/tmp/home/username`), changing the uid, and then changing the homedir back to what it was.

For example:

```sh
# mkdir -p /tmp/home/jsmith  ## uncomment if required.
usermod -d /tmp/home/jsmith jsmith
usermod -u fixedUID jsmith -o
usermod -d /home/jsmith jsmith
```

If the user's home directory isn't `/home/username`, you can extract the real home directory with `getent`:

```sh
# mkdir -p /tmp/home/jsmith  ## uncomment if required.
homedir=$(getent passwd jsmith | awk -F: '{print $6}')
usermod -d /tmp/home/jsmith jsmith
usermod -u fixedUID jsmith -o
usermod -d "$homedir" jsmith
```

Comment: you could get the shell to do the getent work for you: `homedir=~jsmith`.

Comment: true, but I like `getent` and think it's under-utilised and not as widely known as it should be.  Also, using it in an answer is a good way of highlighting the fact that it's better to use `getent` than to, e.g., just run `awk` or `grep` or whatever on `/etc/passwd` (depending on nsswitch or pam etc, `/etc/passwd` may not be the only source of login details).