# Change user ID of user in Linux, but don't touch the files in the home directory

Tags: ubuntu, usermod

I want to change the user ID of `www-data`, but not touch the files in the home directory.

usermod man page:

```
   -u, --uid UID
       The new numerical value of the user's ID.

       This value must be unique, unless the -o option is used. The value must be non-negative.

       The user's mailbox, and any files which the user owns and which are located in the user's home directory will have the file
       user ID changed automatically.

       The ownership of files outside of the user's home directory must be fixed manually.
```

So is there a way to execute this without that side effect or do I have to edit `/etc/passwd` manually using `sed` or something like that?

Comment: Maybe [changing the user's home directory name temporarily](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/267905/266568) ...

Comment: Okay, would work, wondering if there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: You mean you want to change the UID, but keep the files in the user's home owned by the old UID, so no longer actually owned by the `www-data` user?

Comment: Actually I am correcting the user ID, it's in a docker setup and the `/var/www` folder is mounted, so the files already should have the correct ID, but the user's ID is not the right one.